'Tag mismatch' when adding Maven dependency in IntelliJ IDEA
I'm encountering an issue when trying to add a dependency in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven. Specifically, I'm getting the following error message:

Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.100 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Tag mismatch

Not only for this dependency, i faced this problem for many dependency
**Code: **
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kanish.</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootWeb1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootWeb1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot web</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>

       

Error log:

Unresolved dependency: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.100'

I am using
IntelliJ IDEA's built-in Maven support
version:
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-241.14494.240, built on March 28, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+8-b1207.12 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  idea.plugin.protoeditor (241.14494.150)
Kotlin: 241.14494.240-IJ

Windows 11


Please show the full pom file...

Your pom works fine on my side. Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for full error message. It looks like some connection issue.

yes, you are right. It's because of internet problem, now it's work properly.
